# A problem about measure theory, symmetric difference and aproxiamation

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

> **Problem:** Let $I\subseteq [0,1]$ and suppose that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a Lebesgue-measure set $J$ such that $$\mu^{*}(I\triangle J)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$Prove that $I$ is Lebesgue-measure set.

> **Notation:** Here $\mu^{*}$ is the outer measure.

**My solution:** Since $J$ is Lebesgue-measure, so for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a open $$\mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$$
such that $$J \subseteq \mathcal{O} \quad \text{and} \quad \mu^{*}(\mathcal{O}\setminus J)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Now, since that $$\boxed{(\mathcal{O}\setminus I) \subset (I \triangle J) \cup (\mathcal{O}\setminus J)} \implies \mu^{*}(\mathcal{O}\setminus I) \leq \mu^{*}((I \triangle J) \cup (\mathcal{O}\setminus J))=\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$

Therefore, $A$ is Lebesgue measure (measure) set.

---

I have posted this test twice before here because I have been working on this issue.
I'm new to solving measure theory problems, but I really like it.
**I would like to know if my test is correct and if something could improve it or better justify a part.** *I'm also interested in a solution with a different or more interesting approach*. Thank you!

Comment: What definition for Lebesgue measurable are you using here?

Comment: Hi! I'm using the definition: $A$ is Lebesgue measurable set $\iff \forall \epsilon>0, \exists G_{open}: A\subseteq G$ and $\mu^{*}(G\setminus A)<\epsilon$.